# Controlling Internet Explorer instance VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, automation

Not too long ago I had written some code in VBA that generates two separate internet explorer sessions (each with its own cookie).

I have worked with forms and the IE WebControl in visual studio 2013 before, but found that it has compatibility issues with some sites. This is why I am attempting to open external browsers so that compatibility issues won't be a problem.

I have added all needed references to my VB.NET project and the below code more or less runs without issue. However, after I create both IE instances, I am unable to make the browsers visible even though I utilize to visible property to make them so.

Most examples I have found online only give examples using WebControl, which I am trying to avoid. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
Imports class SHDocVw
Public Class Form1
Public shellWins As ShellWindows
Public shellWins2 As ShellWindows
Public ie1 As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Public ie2 As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'New Object
Public ieU As Object
Public ieP As Object
Public ieU2 As Object
Public ieP2 As Object
Public oWin As New Object
Public oWin2 As New Object
Public sh As New Object  


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

shellWins = New ShellWindows
shellWins2 = New ShellWindows

ie1 = shellWins.Item(0)
ie1 = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie1 = shellWins.Item(0)
ie2 = ie1

ie1.Navigate("https://www.SomeSite123.com")
ie1.visible = true

ie2.Navigate("https://www.SomeSite123.com")
ie2.visible = true

ieWait1()
ieWait2()

ieU = ie1.document.getElementById("uName")
ieP = ie1.document.getElementById("uPass")
ieU.Value = "user123"
ieP.value = "Abc123"

ieU2 = ie2,document.getElementById("uPass")
ieP2 = ie2.document.getElementById("uName")
ieU2.Value = "user123"
ieP2.value = "Abc123"   

ieWait1()
ieWait2()


end sub

end class
```

Comment: What compatibility issues are you talking about that the webbrowser control had? I ask because by default the webbrowser control uses the IE7 rendering engine...but you can tell it to use the latest IE Edge.

Comment: It looks like I was able to get around the compatibility issue I was having. However, when I try to access an element within the webbrowser control, I get an error. ieU = WebBrowser1.document.getElementById("uName"), ieU.value = "User123". I get a "Missing Member Exception

Answer (score 0):

To make the `WebBrowser` control use the latest installed IE version on your computer refer to this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367088/3740093

As for the error you're getting: `MissingMemberException` occurs because the resulting [**`HtmlElement` object**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) that you get from the `WebBrowser` doesn't contain a property or method called `Value`. To get or set an element's [**`value` attribute**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) you have to use the [**`HtmlElement.GetAttribute()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [**`HtmlElement.SetAttribute()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

For your specific case:

```
ieU.SetAttribute("value", "user123")
ieP.SetAttribute("value", "Abc123")
```

---

Also, I ***strongly*** recommend you change your variable declarations from `Object` to `HtmlElement` to avoid late-binding and these kinds of errors:

```
Public ieU As HtmlElement
Public ieP As HtmlElement
Public ieU2 As HtmlElement
Public ieP2 As HtmlElement
```

Now your application won't even compile if you try to access a member that doesn't exist. Thus saving you the trouble of having to debug it.

---

Finally, I couldn't help but notice your `ieWait` methods. I just want you to know that if they're calling `Application.DoEvents()` (which I'm pretty sure they do) you need to get rid of them at once! Using `Application.DoEvents()` to keep your UI responsive is in 99% of the cases ***bad practice*** because it is almost always used **incorrectly**.

Instead you should use the [**`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx), which is raised every time the page (or a frame in the page) is loaded.

In this answer of mine there's an example on how you can use the `DocumentCompleted` event more dynamically in inline code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110795/3740093

- Note that you can use multiple lambda expressions within each other.