# How to wait until WebBrowser contains any text in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am using the WebBrowser control in my VB.NET application to load a URL, then wait the page is contains the text "done" and msgbox ("done")

I tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("<my url>")
        Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        Do Until WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText.Contains("done")
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        MsgBox("done")
```

Cheers!

Comment: P/s: It's show that:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Document.get returned Nothing.

Comment: Rudimetary research on this subject would have shown you that you need to handle the `DocumentCompleted` event of the `WebBrowser`.  **NEVER** call `Application.DoEvents` alone in a loop.  If you think you need to, you know you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney how can I solve it?

Comment: You can solve it by doing the research that you should have done before posting.  I've told you what event to handle.  What is stopping you reading the documentation for that event and looking for examples of its use on the web?

Comment: I removed the Application.DoEvents() but it doesn't work

Comment: I specifiaclly told you that you need to handle the `DocumentCompleted` event.  If you haven't done that then why would you expect it to work?  If you're just going to ignore advice when it's provided then why ask a question?  If you assume that people will just write your code for you every time then you'll be sorely disappointed.  When someone gives you the name of a type or member that you should use, you need to immediately start researching that type or member to find out FOR YOURSELF how it gets used.

Comment: In my answer to this question I explain two different ways of waiting for a specific element to appear, depending on whether it is loaded with the page or via Javascript after the page has loaded: Possible duplicate of [How to create a waiting timer that does not stop the loading of a WebBrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110456/how-to-create-a-waiting-timer-that-does-not-stop-the-loading-of-a-webbrowser)